# Factory method HTTP not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I cannot get this json call from my factory `jsonLanguage`.

My code:

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);
var theLanguage = 'english';
App.factory('jsonLanguage', function($http){
    var theLanguage = 'english';
    return {

        get: function(theLanguage){
            var url = theLanguage + '.json';
            $http.get(url);
        }
    }

});
App.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http, $log, jsonLanguage) {

  //$http.get(theLanguage + '.json')

       jsonLanguage.success(function(res){  //here is the problem I tried .then and tried res.data no luck :(
          $scope.language = res;
$log.debug($scope.language);


        });
$log.debug($scope.language);
angular.forEach($scope.letter, function(single) {
        $log.log("hello worldsss");
 $log.log(single);
    });
});

App.controller('intervalController', function($scope, $log) {
    this.$log = $log;
    //var name = $scope.single;
    angular.forEach($scope.letter, function(single) {
        $log.log("hello worldsss");
 $log.log(single);
    });
    //$log.log(name);
  $log.log('Hello World!');

});

App.controller('clickController', function($scope) {

});
```

I tried `jsonLanguage`, and then and tried `res.data` with no luck.

Comment: The error is TypeError: jsonLanguage.success is not a function

Comment: I think you might want to define a provider... if you want an object that you can change some properties of in a config block before angular starts using it then a provider makes sense.

Comment: @shaunhusain Thanks shaun How would I go about doing that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you missed couple of things:

1. Return `$http` promise from service `get method`

   ```
   get: function(theLanguage){
       return $http.get(url);
   }
   ```
2. Call factory `get method` & get data inside its promise success by putting `.then` over that method call.

   ```
   jsonLanguage.get($scope.language).then(function(res){ 
      $scope.language = res.data;
   });
   ```

Comment: Why do I need to put $scope.languge in the `get method` you must have meant $scope.theLanguage

Comment: @AaronRabinowitz I found `language` $scope variable inside your controller, so I added that. If variable name is `theLanguage` then pass that..

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `jsonLanguage.get().then(/**insert callback fn here*/)` in order to call the service.

And in order for that to work, you need to return the promise in your get function.

```
get: function(theLanguage){
    return $http.get(url);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Return the `$http` promise, so that you can resolve it later using `then`.

```
return {
  get: function(theLanguage) {
    var url = theLanguage + '.json';
    return $http.get(url);
  }
}
```

Now you can use it like `jsonLanguage.get().then()`